# Extract String Regex

Tags: c#

```
LogHit('EJI2BLMIF9T9HVC','E','MK9LBROIB0MPI23');
```

How to extract `EJI2BLMIF9T9HVC`, using `Regex.Match`, the `'LogHit'` is constant, the `'EJI2BLMIF9T9HVC'` is variable.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need regex for such a simple thing?

Comment: its only 1 line from a html page, I need to retrieve the LogHit Id, in this example it is 'EJI2BLMIF9T9HVC'

Comment: use this pattern.`@"LogHit\('(\w*)"`

Comment: @ M.kazem Akhgary. Thank you sir, I still dont understand what is the difference between \w+ and \w* , I tried with \w+ before and it doesnt work

Comment: just btw. here an good site for creating some regex's: http://www.regex101.com

Comment: @shadowlif thx sir, its a very nice information

Comment: Using `Regex.Match()` for something as simple as this is not really necessary. You can do the same thing using `string.Split()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = "LogHit('EJI2BLMIF9T9HVC','E','MK9LBROIB0MPI23');";
Match match = Regex.Match(s, "^LogHit\\('([^']+)'");

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); // EJI2BLMIF9T9HVC
```

Comment: this one also works, but I remove the "^" to make it work for my code, its :  "LogHit\\('([^']+)'", thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "LogHit('EJI2BLMIF9T9HVC','E','MK9LBROIB0MPI23');"; 
Regex.Match(s, @"\('([^']*)'").Groups[1].Value;
```